# IntentHandler doesn't work with widgetFamily

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, ios14, widgetkit

I added an Intent Extension Target to my project and I'm trying to distinguish which widget type is displayed during edit mode in `IntentHandler` and based on this information I want to populate the "Edit Widget" list with small, medium or large widget types.

When I use `@Environment(\.widgetFamily) var family` it gives me `.systemMedium` all the time but I'm editing a large size of widget at that time.

For ex; When I long-press a small widget to edit and select another widget type from the list, and I see a list full of items containing small, medium, and large widget types from `IntentHandler` but I want to see only small types.

The question is that possible to fill the list depending on which type of widget that I'm currently editing?

Comment: Could you share your IntentHandler code? It should be in your main app or an Intent extension; SwiftUI stuff like `@Environment(\.widgetFamily)` won’t work outside of your widget code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you’re trying to do, I think the answer is no, it’s not possible. To replicate what apps like Widgetsmith do, you’ll need to define 3 separate Widgets, one for each of small, medium, and large `supportedFamily` sizes. Then define 3 separate Intents, one for each widget, and implement a separate Intent Handler for each one.

Something like this:

```
@main
struct MyWidgetBundle: WidgetBundle {
    @WidgetBundleBuilder
    var body: some Widget {
        SmallWidget()
        MediumWidget()
        LargeWidget()
    }
}

struct SmallWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "SmallWidget"
    
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: SmallWidgetIntent.self, provider: TimelineProvider()) { entry in
            WidgetView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Small Widget")
        .supportedFamilies([.systemSmall])
    }
}

struct MediumWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "MediumWidget"
    
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: MediumWidgetIntent.self, provider: TimelineProvider()) { entry in
            WidgetView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Medium Widget")
        .supportedFamilies([.systemMedium])
    }
}

struct LargeWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "LargeWidget"
    
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: LargeWidgetIntent.self, provider: TimelineProvider()) { entry in
            WidgetView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Large Widget")
        .supportedFamilies([.systemLarge])
    }
}
```

In your Intent Definition file, define `SmallWidgetIntent`, `MediumWidgetIntent`, and `LargeWidgetIntent`. And then in your intent handler, you’d implement `SmallWidgetIntentHandling`, `MediumWidgetIntentHandling`, and `LargeWidgetIntentHandling`, which would return the correct options for their associated size.

Comment: Thanks Adam! As you mentioned that I split it into 3 different widgets and combine them using WidgetBuilder. Now I have a single IntentHandler class that conforms to 3 IntentHandling. That works!!! Thanks again!

Comment: Also is needed to create separate TimelineProviders for each family?

Comment: @iOS Dev You can use the same TimelineProvider for all your widgets.

Comment: @Adam But in my custom IntentTimelineProvider I must set the Intent typealias, but I'm having 3 different intents as you suggested.

Comment: @iodev You’re right, sorry I misread that. You do need separate IntentTimelineProviders for each Intent.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I'm making new app like Widgetsmith but it is free